# PHP Alterar texto em OpenOffice xml com XMLReader e XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, office-open-xml

Preciso alterar o conteúdo das tags  de um documento openoffice e copiar o restante do conteúdo do documento. O problema não está em encontrar a tag  e substituir o seu conteúdo, mas em copiar as tags pais e seus atributos corretamente, utilizando xmlreader e xmlwriter. Abaixo um rascunho do código:

texts.xml

```
<texts>
 <text id="1">Lorem Ipsum</text>
 <text id="2">dolor sit amet</text>
 <text id="3">consectetur adipiscing elit. </text>
 <text id="4">Nunc vel justo vitae risus fermentum</text>
</texts>
```

document.xml (exemplo retirado de [officeopenxml.com](http://officeopenxml.com/WPsampleDoc.php))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
<w:body>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
   <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>Introduction</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">My children love many nursery rhymes and childhood songs. </w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r><w:t>Favorites</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
   <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
  </w:pPr>
   <w:r><w:t>Humpty Dumpty</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
   <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">None are more beloved than </w:t>           </w:r>
   <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr>
     <w:t>Humpty Dumpty</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">.     </w:t>
   </w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
  <w:spacing w:before="120" w:after="120"/>
  <w:ind w:left="720" w:right="720"/>
  <w:rPr>
   <w:sz w:val="18"/>
   </w:rPr>
 </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
  <w:rPr>
  <w:sz w:val="18"/>
  </w:rPr>
   <w:t xml:space="preserve">Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall. </w:t>
   </w:r>
 . . .
 </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

PHP

```
$original = new XMLReader;
$source = new XMLReader;
$original->open('document.xml');
$source->open('texts.xml')
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('new_dpcument.xml');
$writer->setIndent(true);
$writer->startDocument("1.0");
$t = 0;
while ($original->read()){
 if ($original->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $original->name !== 'w:t'){ 
  //while the node isn't text node (<w:t>), I'd like to copy everything as is to the new_document.xml. I can just use $content = $original->readOuterXML(); and $writer->writeRaw($content); for nodes not related to w:t,  but it won't work for w:t parent nodes.
}elseif ($original->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $original->name === 'w:t'){
//now that it's a w:t I need to replace its content.
$source->next('text');
$content = $source->readInnerXML($source);
$writer->startElement('w:t');
 $writer->text($content); 
$writer->endElement();
}
}
$writer->endDocument();
$writer->flush();
```

O resultado deveria ser algo assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
<w:body>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
   <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>Lorem Ipsum</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">dolor sit amet</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r><w:t>consectur adipiscing elit. </w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
   <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
  </w:pPr>
   <w:r><w:t>Nunc vel justo vitae risus fermentum</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
   <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">None are more beloved than </w:t>           </w:r>
   <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr>
     <w:t>Humpty Dumpty</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">.     </w:t>
   </w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
  <w:spacing w:before="120" w:after="120"/>
  <w:ind w:left="720" w:right="720"/>
  <w:rPr>
   <w:sz w:val="18"/>
   </w:rPr>
 </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
  <w:rPr>
  <w:sz w:val="18"/>
  </w:rPr>
   <w:t xml:space="preserve">Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall. </w:t>
   </w:r>
 . . .
 </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com [uma resposta do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990798/php-replace-text-in-office-openxml-files-with-xmlwriter-xmlreader/29043993#29043993)

Estou utilizando para isso a classe [XMLReaderIterator versão 0.1.8](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator/commit/21275f9fd6dd13f3e78d4829280dd7f0c26ce8da)

Abaixo o código:

```
require('xmlreader-iterators.php'); // require XMLReaderIterator library

$xmlInputFile = 'data/worddocument.xml';
$xmlXliffFile = 'data/segments.xliff';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlInputFile);

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();

$iterator = new XMLWritingIteration($writer, $reader);

$writer->startDocument();

$textCount = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    $isElement = $node->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT;

    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'w:t') {
        $textCount++;

        $writer->startElement($node->name);

        $node->next();
        $iterator->skipNextRead();

        $writer->text(sprintf("TEXT #%d", $textCount));
        $writer->endElement();
    } else {
        // handle everything else
        $iterator->write();
    }
}

$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->outputMemory(true);
```